# Why UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods not called specifically in Portrait mode of device rotation?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have a Collection view inside UIView. I want to auto resize the cell on device rotation(i.e there will be 4 columns in **potrait** mode and 5 columns in **landscape** mode). In the first time(when initially app launched) working fine but when I rotate the device to Portrait mode again from landscape mode, FlowLayout delegate methods not getting called.

Here is  my code:

```
    class GridViewNw: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var gridCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var imgArrCount: Int = 20

    var gridLeading: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var gridTrailing: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var gridTop: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var gridBottom: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var gridWidth: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var gridLeft: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var gridRight: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var gridCenter: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)


        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout() 
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        gridCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        gridCollectionView.dataSource = self
        gridCollectionView.delegate = self
        gridCollectionView.register(GridViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "gridViewCell")
        gridCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        gridCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(gridCollectionView)


        gridTop = gridCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0)
        gridTop?.isActive = true

        gridCenter = gridCollectionView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor)
        gridCenter?.isActive = true


        gridLeft = gridCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0)
        gridLeft?.isActive = true
        gridRight = gridCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0)
        gridRight?.isActive = true


        gridBottom = gridCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        gridBottom?.isActive = true

        gridCollectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout

        //NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)

        //layout.prepare()
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func getImgSize() -> (width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, itemGap: CGFloat, collVwWidth: CGFloat){

        var imgWidth: CGFloat = 115
        var imgHeight: CGFloat = 173

        let viewWidth: CGFloat = self.bounds.width
        var columnCount: Int = 3
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {

            imgWidth = 157
            imgHeight = 236

            columnCount = 4
            let interfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
            if interfaceOrientation == .landscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == .landscapeRight {
                columnCount = 5
            }
        }

        let gapCount: Int = columnCount - 1 //CGFloat(columnCount * 2) //CGFloat(columnCount - 1)
        let minimumGap: CGFloat = 10
        var totalGap: CGFloat = minimumGap * CGFloat(gapCount)
        var collectionViewWidth: CGFloat = viewWidth - totalGap

        let remainder = Int(collectionViewWidth) % columnCount
        totalGap = totalGap + CGFloat(remainder)
        let itemGap = totalGap / CGFloat(gapCount)
        collectionViewWidth = collectionViewWidth - CGFloat(remainder)
        let itemWidth: CGFloat = (collectionViewWidth - totalGap) / CGFloat(columnCount) //(collectionViewWidth / CGFloat(columnCount)) - (minimumGap * 2)
        let itemHeight: CGFloat = (imgHeight / imgWidth) * itemWidth

        return (itemWidth, itemHeight, itemGap, collectionViewWidth)
    }

}
extension GridViewNw: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgArrCount
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let imageCell : GridViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "gridViewCell", for: indexPath) as! GridViewCell
        //imageCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        let img = getImgSize()
        imageCell.displayAssetImage(imgWidth: img.width, imgHeight: img.height)

        imageCell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        imageCell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        return imageCell
    }


}
extension GridViewNw : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        print("sizeForItemAt")
        let img = getImgSize()
        return CGSize(width: img.width, height: img.height)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        print("insetForSectionAt")
        let img = getImgSize()
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, img.itemGap, 0, img.itemGap)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        print("minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt")
        let img = getImgSize()
        return img.itemGap
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you hook up you delegate and datasource properly with your view controller ??

Comment: @Rumy, I am using UIView, the collectionview is in side UIView. Yes I hook up you delegate and datasource properly. Please look at to my updated code.

Comment: Can I see your ViewController code by github or any other hosting site. Seeing your code I may help you. Usually that should not occur.

Comment: Please look at to my updated code.

Comment: hmmm.wait, I try it to figure out.

Comment: let me know is your problem solved?

Comment: @Rumy, I am using UIView(clearly mentioned), how can I override viewWillTransition?

Answer (score 0):

Check `viewwilltransition` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and update your `itemsize` as you want.To know more about [viewwilltransition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition) and [viewDidLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews) show the links.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: 
         UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    updateCV(with: size)
}
```

Here If view transition happen I call a method name `updateCV` and in this method I update the `itemsize` as I want.

```
func updateCV(with size: CGSize) {
    if let layout = cv.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout 
     {
      // add your custom layout here
        layout.itemSize = (size.width < size.height) ? itemSizeForPortraitMode : itemSizeForLandscapeMode
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using UIView(clearly mentioned), how can I override viewWillTransition?